# Combining Query and If Statements in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I need to know if this is possible:

I have a data in Google Sheets. I want to do a query on the data itself.

I want to be able to query any data that has a certain cell filled in with a date format. If the cell is filled in with a date format, then the data is transferred over to the query but if it does not contains date data in the cell, then the data won't get queried over.

So Is it possible to put a nested if statement in Query?

For example this is the workflow of the query

Check if Date cell is filled with data >> Check for the Broker name >> Select Column B and F to show in the query

Below is my Query formula so far:

```
=QUERY({Funded_2022!A:AM, if(Not(IsBlank(W:W)))}, "Select B, F")
```

[image]

and its coming with the error message:

Function ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 has mismatched row size. Expected: 2002. Actual: 1

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=QUERY({Funded_2022!B:B, Funded_2022!F:F, Funded_2022!W:W},
 "select Col1,Col2 where Col3 is not null", )
```

Comment: Morning Player0

I did put the codes within Google Sheets and it did not work and gives me back this error:
Error
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: C

I added a picture of my column and its respective lettering to it

I wanted to just write a query where if there is a value in column W and it is equal to a broker name on Column D , it would query column B and C

Thank you

Comment: @EngineeringCFS answer updated. use Col references